# SQL Server Performance on Primary Key Index

Tags: sql-server

I've been asked on interview the question similar to this:

The company has the following tables in the SQL Server:

```
SalesHeader
    HeaderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    SalesManagerID INT NOT NULL

SalesLine
    SalesID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    HeaderID INT NOT NULL,
    ProductID INT NOT NULL,
    ProductDiscount FLOAT NOT NULL
```

Given the query:

```
SELECT HeaderID FROM SalesHeader AS sh
WHERE 0.1 IN (SELECT ProductDiscount 
              FROM SalesLine AS sl 
              WHERE sh.HeaderID = sl.HeaderID)
```

The question was about performance of this query: How many time will a lookup occur on the primary key index of the `SalesLine` table?

What is the answer provided the `SalesHeader` has 10000 rows and `SalesLine` has 15000 rows? And why? And what if `SalesLine` has 5000 rows?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the execution plan of a test scenario?

Comment: Before we considering answer this, what you was your answer? If you're asking a *homework/interview/etc help* question on Stack Overflow, the guidelines advise that you show your efforts first. If we simply provide you with the answer, you won't learn as much as if you were to try and solve the problem yourself (such as by trial and error, research, etc).

Comment: @Larnu My answer was 10000 for case when SalesLine has 15000 rows and 5000 for case when SalesLine has 5000. Interviewer told me it is wrong but hasn't explained why.

Comment: My answer would be `why isn't SalesLine.HeaderID indexed?`.

Comment: My second answer would be "whatever you think it is, it's wrong but performance will be bad". Performance will be *bad* because the inner query will have to be repeated for every value in the outer query, just to get the matching rows. The *interviewer can't know the actual number either!!!*. The query optimizer could decide that filtering by `ProductDiscount  =0.1` is cheaper and start from *there* before performing the JOIN. You can't know that without having an idea of the data statistics though.

Comment: if you want to see the plan and time it taken in details use execution plan in toolbar and see how sql do this query

Comment: My approach would be to reply with an assumption and an improved query. There should be a foreign key between the tables based on HeaderID. And FKs should be indexed. These are assumptions that need to be spoken. Therefore there is no need to join the tables in any way. The resultset can be generated directly from the detail table. So the answer is NONE! And argue that the original query is garbage (but nicely). No FK or no indexes? Then the question is garbage.